# Is it true that $\lim_{x→x_0} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{h→0} f(x_0 + h^ 2 ) = L$?

Tags: real-analysis

For context, the previous question was very similar:

Prove that that $\lim_{x→x_0} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{h→0} f(x_0 + h) = L$?

I found this to be an easy proof by letting *$h=x-x_0$*. But the following question makes me unsure about my understanding of *h* here:

Is it true that $\lim_{x→x_0}
f(x) = L \iff \lim_{h→0} f(x_0 + h^
2
) = L$?

I think I can prove the forward direction by letting $h^2=x-x_0$, but my professor defined  *$h=x-x_0$* in class when moving between the equivalent expressions of limits in the first problem. So I guess I don't really understand what *h* is here. Can I make it anything I want?

Comment: What happens if $f(x)=1$ for $x\ge0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\geq0\\0&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}.$$
Then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ is undefined but $\lim_{h\to0}f(0+h^2)=\lim_{h\to0}f(h^2)=\lim_{h\to0}1=1$, since $h^2\geq0$. You only check for the right limit with the second definition, while the first definition considers both left and right limit.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Just curious: Would the forward direction hold? How might I prove it?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{t\to 0}f(x_0+t)$. Now substitute $t=h^2$: if $h\to0$ then $t\to0$, so $\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h^2) = \lim_{h^2\to0}f(x+h^2) = \lim_{t\to0}f(x+t)$ assuming all limits exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h^2) = L$, then because $h^2 > 0$ for every $h\ne 0$, we can only say that the right-hand limit $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x) = L$ holds.

In order to be able to say $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) = L$, we would also need to know $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0-h^2) = L$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

Both versions of the first statement say that $f(x)$ is near $L$ when $x$ is near $x_0$.

The right hand side of the second expression says that $f(x)$ is near $L$ when $x$ is *larger than* $x_0$ and near $x_0$.

That is not equivalent to the first statement.